# Tcl: Add special characters in a list

Tags: tcl

I would like add this : `` var mylinechart = `{ `` in a list

```
set myvar "var mylinechart = `\{"
> var mylinechart = `{
lappend mylist $myvar
> var\ mylinechart\ =\ `\{
```

the expected result is not that desired... I would like this :
`` {var mylinechart = `{} ``
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tcl printer doesn't normally add brackets around an outer list, or list elements that aren't themselves lists. But if you have a multi-dimensional list, then you start to see them:

```
% set mylist [list a b c]
a b c
% lappend mylist [list $myvar]
a b c {var\ mylinechart\ =\ `\{}
```

`mylist` is now a list of four elements, the last of which is a list with a single element. It still backslashes all the spaces so the whole thing is treated as a single element. If you're doing something like writing to a file and don't want to see them, you can use `puts` on that element:

```
% puts [lindex $mylist 3 0]
var mylinechart = `{
```

Answer (score 1):

The Tcl list formatter prefers to use neither braces nor backslashes, but if that doesn't work (perhaps because the element contains a space or other Tcl metacharacter) then it uses braces, but if *that* doesn't work (usually because the element has unbalanced braces) then it uses backslashes. Backslashes are the ugliest option, but work for anything.

Your example value has an unbalanced brace. That means when Tcl formats the list, it uses backslashes. That might be ugly, but it works and you can recover the value with `lindex` so it *must* be correct.

Tcl does not give you control over the format rules it chooses to use when it formats a list, at least not at the script level. (There's a little more control possible if you poke around at the C library level, but *it's not advised* and all you can ever really safely do is force things to become uglier. You can't safely make it not use backslashes.)

---

To reinforce, what you wanted, `` {var mylinechart = `{} ``, is *not a well-formed list.* (I'm putting it in double quotes below so I can easily enter it; that in itself is a clue that it's a bad thing.)

```sh
% set s "{var mylinechart = `{}"
{var mylinechart = `{}
% lindex $s 0
unmatched open brace in list
```